# Assignments in C

Tags: c, assignment-operator

Can you write something like this in C with multiple assignment operations?

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
(((a = b) = c) = d);
```

I've read somewhere that C standard states that the result of this won't be lvalue? is this undefined?

Comment: This [does not compile](http://www.ideone.com/oOTuS), it's not undefined behavior. The value of what exactly should be set to `c`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do

```
a = b = c = d;
```

which is the same as

```
a = (b = (c = d));
```

As you say, the (sub-)expression `(a = b)` is not an *lvalue* and can't be assigned a value.

Comment: Is this really true? I thought the order of evaluation was unspecified behaviour, meaning that this might as well be evaluated left-to-right. Does that matter? Yes, if those are volatile variables, the result of left-to-right evaluation might turn out to be different.

Comment: Lundin: K&R table 2.1. = is right-associative. The order of evaluation being unspecified means that b might be evaluated before a (it makes more sense with K&R's example of function calls). Section 2.12, pg. 52ff in the second edition.

Comment: @Lundin: the order of evaluation is unspecified behaviour. In `a = (b = c)`, `a`, a *lvalue*, and `(b = c)` need to be evaluated before the assignment. Once they're evaluated, in any order, (and only after both are evaluated), the assignment of the value `(b = c)` can take place.

Answer (score 0):

`a=b` returns value of `b` which won't be lvalue, and that's the reason why the value of `c` can't be assigned to that expression.
With parentheses you are changing usual order of assignments.

```
a = b = c = d;
```

in this case value of `d` is assigned to `c`, then value of `c` to `b`, then value of `b` to `a`.

Comment: This is incorrect as a=b returns the value of a. From the standard: "An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment.". Specifying this might seem unnecessary, but consider the case where a is a bool and b is an int.

Answer (score 0):

```
     a=b=c=d;
```

is same as

```
    (a = (b = (c = d)));
```

because '=' operator assign right to left..